# set object's value in local storage

Tags: javascript, json, storage, local

> Need to add Objects in local storage and also use them same time. But code showing "noteObj.push is not a function"

```js
// add a Event Listener in #add-btn and gat 2 input textlet addBtn = document.getElementById("add-btn");
addBtn.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    let addTextHeading = document.getElementById('add-text-heading').value;
    let addTextBody = document.getElementById('add-text-body').value;
    // get value form localStorage
    let notes = localStorage.getItem('notes');
    if (notes == null) {
        noteObj = []
    }
    else {
        noteObj = JSON.parse(notes)
    }
    // add value in localStorage
    let myObj = {
        heading: addTextHeading,
        body: addTextBody
    }
    noteObj.push(myObj)
    localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(noteObj))
})
```

Comment: Just declare `noteObj` like `let noteObj;` just above if condition.

Comment: make sure you are getting an array at `noteObj = JSON.parse(notes)` so you can use .push()

Comment: I agree with @user9879287. The only way you'd get this error is if the data in local storage is present but not a JSON array representation. Perhaps it's an object, string or number?